# A vowel at the beginning or the end of a string

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I have a homework question that I want to see if I did correctly.

The question asks

> How many strings of $4$ letters begin or end with one of the five vowels?

I got $5 \cdot 26^2 \cdot 5$ for my final answer. My thinking was that for the first spot, you only have $5$ possible choices, the next $2$ spots of the string can be any letter of the alphabet, and then the last spot also has to be a vowel, so you only have $5$ choices for that. Is my thinking and answer correct?

Comment: Note;  your header question is not the same as the question in the body of your post.  Which one did you intend to ask?

Comment: Be careful as you read the question.  The question asks how many strings of 4 letters begin **OR** end with one of the five vowels.  Your answer of $5\cdot 26^2\cdot 5$ is the answer to the question of how many strings of 4 letters begin **AND** end with one of the five vowels.

Comment: For a corrected approach, use inclusion-exclusion:  $|A\cup B| = |A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$.  Let $A$ be the set of 4-letter strings which begin with a vowel.  Let $B$ represent the set of 4-letter strings which end with a vowel.

Comment: Looks like I misread my homework question. Oops. I intended to ask for OR. In that case, would the solution `(5*26^3)+(5*26^3)-(5*26^2*5)` the correct answer then?

Comment: That looks good.  Another approach is to note that there are $26^4$ strings in all, and $21^2\times 26^2$ begin and end with consonants, so the answer is $26^4-21^2\times 26^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarizer the discussion in the comments:

The question is asking for the number of four letter strings that can be formed out of the usual $26$ (repetitions allowed) where we require that at least one of the first and last letters be chosen from the $5$ standard vowels.  The solution proposed in the original post is incorrect, as it counts those strings in which both the first and last letters are vowels.

Two methods of solution were discussed in the comments.

Method I: direct

There are $5\times 26^3$ strings of length $4$ that begin with a vowel, and the same number that end in a vowel.  If we simply add these, we double count those strings which both begin and end in a vowel.  Hence we have to subtract those.  Thus the answer is $$2\times 5\times 26^3-5^2\times 26^2=158860$$

Method II:  from the complement

It is easy to count the strings which fail our test; these are the strings that both begin and end with one of the $21$ consonants.  Thus there are $21^2\times 26^2$ of these.  As there are $26^4$ strings in total, the answer is $$26^4-21^2\times 26^2=158860$$

Answer (score 0):

The number 4 strings begining or ending in a vowel = the number of 4 strings begining in a vowel and not ending in a vowel + the number of 4 strings not begining in a vowel and ending in a vowel + the number of 4 strings beginning and ending in a vowel.

You answered with the number of 4 strings beginning and ending in a vowel.